# AlertDialog Incompatible types error

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

I keep trying to compile this simple alert dialog to display when the user clicks the submit button. An error message pops up when the code is being compiled:

> *Error:(33, 74) error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context*

This class is called Login_Activity, which extends BaseActivity, which extends Activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mUserNameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username_et);
    mPasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password_et);
    mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_submit_btn);

    mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            messageBox.setTitle("Atlas Box");
            messageBox.setMessage("Dictionary.");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change

```
AlertDialog.Builder messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(youractivityname.this);
```